# Code Igniter: Creating a blog cms: display a blog post that is given in the URL

Tags: codeigniter, routes, system, blogs, posts

URL: www.blog.com/posts/category/post-title

How do I create a controller, that accepts the two parts of the URL "category" and "post-title" and echoes out the post?

Thank you a lot.

Timo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `CodeIgniter` the `URL` is mapped as `domain/Controller/Method/params`, so following `URL`

```
www.blog.com/posts/category/post-title
```

will be mapped as `posts` is the controller, `category` as method name and rest are parameters. So, You need to create a controller like this:

```
// posts.php
class Posts extends CI_Controller {

    public function show($category, $title)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then the `URL` could be `www.blog.com/posts/show/some-category/post-title` and you can retrieve the `some-category` and `post-title` as parameters in you `show` method. For more information, check [Controllers](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html) on `CI User Guide`.

Comment: how do I get this running? it crashes with an 404 error. i think something goes wrong in the config...

Comment: Did you remove the `index.php` using `.htaccess` file and `config` ?

Comment: [Here is a little help](https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=codeigniter+index.php+remove&oq=codigniter+index&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2.8351j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: THANK YOU, everything is fine and running :D